# Saving long ASPX files in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: windows-7, performance, visual-studio-2010

I'm hoping someone can help me out because I'm extremely close to completely bugging out in the office right now...

So here's the deal; we use Visual Studio 2010 (Ultimate) for web development. The application I'm developing right now is pretty large: about 300mb across 8 projects (including 3rd party libraries). Whenever I work on an ASPX or ASCX (actually it seems to be any file with a codebehind or designer file) file that is over about 100/150 lines it can take up to a solid minute to save. And of course, like most programmers, pressing CTRL-SHIFT-S is so ingrained into my head that it's basically an every-other-minute reflex.

I've combed the google machine (and even *gasp* bing) and found a few things to try but to no avail. I tried disabling any extensions and clearing the MRU cache and all that jazz as well but I still have the same problem. I've also tried disabling (and even uninstalling) Norton Antivirus.

This is the system I'm experiencing the problems on:

- HP EliteBook 8460w
- Intel Core i7-2630QM @ 2.00GHz
- 8GB DDR3 RAM 64-bit
- Windows 7 Professional w/SP1
- ATI FirePro M3900 Mobility
- Toshiba MK5061GSYN 500GB SATA HDD

I considered that perhaps it could be the disk access rate? I have a SSD that I'm going to be installing tonight so I'll update if that ends up fixing it but in the meantime PLEASE if you have any suggestions at all let me know!

Thanks, Jason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way that it should take that long to save an ASP.Net file on a machine of that spec.  I would expect that there are other factors involved.  Personally, I would recommend reinstalling the whole development environment from Windows up.

You mention an SSD - I would certainly use that as it will improve the performance of the whole environment massively (especially if it's SATA 3 connected to a 6 GB/s mobo).  An SSD will improve the install and rebuild time hugely too.

You can consider reducing the pain of reinstalling your development environment in future by booting from a VM image.  Having a backup of that image means you can refresh your Visual Studio environment rapidly and get back to a known, fresh state.  Hansleman talks about this [here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/LessVirtualMoreMachineWindows7AndTheMagicOfBootToVHD.aspx) for Win 7, and again [here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToGuideToInstallingAndBootingWindows8ConsumerPreviewOffAVHDVirtualHardDisk.aspx) for Win 8.  The Rinat Abdullin also does similar but uses Linux as his base OS - see [here](http://abdullin.com/journal/2011/3/16/linux-setup-tweaks-of-net-developer-with-ssd.html) for details.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks Sean! I have absolutely no idea why (I wish I did though), but a complete rebuild on my SSD (128gb Crucial 6gb/s SATA3) not only resolved the problem completely but also runs about a billion times faster just in general AND extended my battery life a ton. Totally worth the extra monies for the SSD.

Comment: Glad to hear that fixed the problem.  And, yes, SSDs totally rock.  Once you start using VS with an SSD, you can't go back!! Be aware that SSDs fail more often than a normal drive and you need to backup appropriately: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2011/05/the-hot-crazy-solid-state-drive-scale.html.